# How to make this JavaScript/jQuery code shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to loop this four times to make it shorter? I am trying to change the class from standing to sitting and then back again one at a time.

```
if(sitting > 0) {
    $('.standing:first-of-type').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
} else {
    $('.sitting:first-of-type').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
}

if(sitting > 1) {
    $('.standing:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
} else {
    $('.sitting:nth-of-type(2)').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
}

if(sitting > 2) {
    $('.standing:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
} else {
    $('.sitting:nth-of-type(3)').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
}

if(sitting > 3) {
    $('.standing:nth-of-type(4)').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
} else {
    $('.sitting:nth-of-type(4)').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
}
```

Comment: sure. Use a counter and `$('.standing:first-of-type').each(function(idx, elem){})`

Comment: Performance wise it surely makes sense to write the DOM selectors to variables (atleast the ones that are equal)

Comment: If your code works and your only issue is that you want to make it more maintainable, you should probably post this question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:lt`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) and [`:gt`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selectors.

`:lt(index)` select all elements at an index less than `index` within the matched set. `:gt(index)` select all elements at an index greater than `index` within the matched set.<sup>From jQuery Docs</sup>

As the class `sitting` should be added to all the elements having class `.standing` whose `index` is less than the `sitting` variable value, `:lt` selector can be used with the variable `sitting` to select such elements. Then [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) can be used on the jQuery set of elements to add and remove the passed classes respectively.

```
$('.standing:lt(' + sitting + ')').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
$('.sitting:gt(' + sitting + ')').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
```

Comment: I like that 2 liner, clever!

Comment: From the available code in question, it looks like it is an integer. I had added `sitting = sitting > 3 ? 3 : sitting < 0 ? 0 : Math.floor(sitting);` in the code but then removed. [Also asked OP to add complete code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458534/how-to-make-this-javascript-shorter#comment58613809_35458534)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do with an ugly for-loop:

```
function toggleSitting(sitting){
    var initial = 0;
    var final = 3;
    for(var i = initial; i <= final; i++){
        $('.standing:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) +')')
            .toggleClass('standing', sitting < i)
            .toggleClass('sitting', sitting > i);
    }
}
toggleSitting(sitting);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a draft and it's untested, but there is a logic in what you are trying to do. Once you find the logic, you just have use it in a loop. Like that :

```
var condition;
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    condition = sitting > i;
    $('.standing:nth-of-type(' + (i + 1) + ')').toggleClass('standing', !condition).toggleClass('sitting', condtion);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Something like this:

```
var numberOfPlaces = 4;

for(var i=0; i<sitting && i<numberOfPlaces ; i++){
    $('.standing:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) + ')').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
}

for(var i=sitting; i<numberOfPlaces ; i++){
    $('.sitting:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) + ')').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
}
```

or this:

```
var numberOfPlaces = 4;

for(var i=0; i<numberOfPlaces; i++){
    if(i<sitting){
        $('.standing:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) + ')').removeClass('standing').addClass('sitting');
    }else if(i>=sitting){
        $('.sitting:nth-of-type(' + (i+1) + ')').removeClass('sitting').addClass('standing');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have HTML and CSS to accompany that ?

You can use a variable to specify the 'nth' of type:

```
$('.standing:nth-of-type(' + i + ')')
```

although not sure that that works for the case where i = 1.  You might need first-of-type there.

Without the CSS and HTML it isn't clear exactly what you want to do.

You might want to look at this also:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/